# Multiple distros in VM with encrypted disk

Tags: distributions, encryption, dm-crypt, openvz

I want to have a GNU/Linux setup on my computer, where I could use different distributions and [isolated environments](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/146695/isolated-environment-for-software-stacks) inside an operating system-level virtual machine. Then I also want to share my personal data between all of the OSes and their configurations. And also this data needs to be encrypted.

**What should my setup look like?**

I thought of the following:

1. Install minimal base distribution like Parabola or Debian.
2. Install VM on it - for example OpenVZ.
3. Install multiple distros inside VM.
4. Create a separate /home partition, which will be encrypted - for example dm-crypt.
5. Share /home partition between distros.

[Any reason for encrypted /?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38874/11397) gave me an idea to use LVM instead of physical partitions, but I had no experience with it. Answers in [Different linux distros sharing the same /home folder?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6344/11397) state that sharing /home can be problematic. What are alternatives or clarifications to the scheme above?

Comment: just for the record openvz is a container and not a full-fledged virtualization, e.g. guests share the kernel and you can see the processes in the host system.